# Periodicity of variables in array in R

Tags: r

Let's say that I have `alpha`

```
alpha = c(a,a,a,b,c,c,c,a,c,c)
```

How can I find the periodicity such that I can construct another array `beta`

```
beta = c(3,1,3,1,2)
```

without using the contents of `alpha` in the code? Is there a way to use lead or lag to answer this?

Comment: Are you looking for run length encoding (`rle`)? I'm not sure what you mean by "without using the contents of alpha". What precisely are your inputs and desired outputs? This seems to do what you describe: `alpha = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "c", "c"); rle(alpha)$lengths`

Comment: I second @MrFlick comment. Also, can you elaborate more what do you mean by using lead or lag to do that?

Comment: thank you! i was looking for rle!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `tabulate` and `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
tabulate(rleid(alpha))
#[1] 3 1 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a convoluted solution:

```
alpha <- c('a','a','a','b','c','c','c','a','c','c');
diff(c(0L,which(c(alpha[-1L]!=alpha[-length(alpha)],T))));
## [1] 3 1 3 1 2
```

## Explanation

---

```
alpha[-1L]!=alpha[-length(alpha)];
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

First compute a logical vector representing which adjacent pairs of input elements constitute breaks in value equality, and which don't. The index of each element in the logical vector corresponds to the index of the first element of the pair in the input vector.

---

```
c(alpha[-1L]!=alpha[-length(alpha)],T);
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Append a `TRUE` value to create a pseudo-break at the end of the vector. See next step for clarification.

---

```
which(c(alpha[-1L]!=alpha[-length(alpha)],T));
## [1]  3  4  7  8 10
```

Convert the logical vector to an index vector representing the *endpoints* of the run lengths in the input vector. Now it should be clear why we had to append `TRUE` in the previous step; the endpoint of the final run length would otherwise be omitted.

---

```
c(0L,which(c(alpha[-1L]!=alpha[-length(alpha)],T)));
## [1]  0  3  4  7  8 10
```

Prepend a zero. This can conceptually be thought of as transforming the index vector into a "boundaries vector", with each element representing either the internal or external boundaries of the input vector run lengths. See next step for clarification.

---

```
diff(c(0L,which(c(alpha[-1L]!=alpha[-length(alpha)],T))));
## [1] 3 1 3 1 2
```

Take the difference between consecutive boundaries. This provides the desired run lengths.

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(data.table);
library(microbenchmark);

bgoldst <- function(alpha) diff(c(0L,which(c(alpha[-1L]!=alpha[-length(alpha)],T))));
akrun <- function(alpha) tabulate(rleid(alpha));
bethany <- function(alpha) { if (length(alpha)==0L) return(integer()); res <- integer(); last <- alpha[1L]; cnt <- 1L; i <- 2L; while (i<=length(alpha)) { if (alpha[i]==last) cnt <- cnt+1L else { res[length(res)+1L] <- cnt; last <- alpha[i]; cnt <- 1L; }; i <- i+1L; }; res[length(res)+1L] <- cnt; res; };
flick <- function(alpha) rle(alpha)$lengths;
```

---

```
alpha <- c('a','a','a','b','c','c','c','a','c','c');

expected <- c(3L,1L,3L,1L,2L);
identical(expected,bgoldst(alpha));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,akrun(alpha));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,bethany(alpha));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,flick(alpha));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(alpha),akrun(alpha),bethany(alpha),flick(alpha));
## Unit: microseconds
##            expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
##  bgoldst(alpha)   8.553  11.1200  14.85308  12.8300  15.3970  70.136   100
##    akrun(alpha) 129.151 144.9745 163.64182 156.7350 171.4895 313.898   100
##  bethany(alpha)  20.101  23.9500  30.43242  26.5155  37.8475  70.136   100
##    flick(alpha)  20.100  23.9495  30.44956  28.0120  32.2890  62.866   100
```

---

```
set.seed(1L); N <- 1e5L; alpha <- sample(letters[1:3],N,T);

expected <- bgoldst(alpha);
identical(expected,akrun(alpha));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,bethany(alpha));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,flick(alpha));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(alpha),akrun(alpha),bethany(alpha),flick(alpha),times=10L);
## Unit: milliseconds
##            expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
##  bgoldst(alpha)    5.497899    6.469098   11.007558    6.521699    7.297460   49.891634    10
##    akrun(alpha)    1.300492    1.370199    1.547461    1.401631    1.464282    2.816091    10
##  bethany(alpha) 2865.335271 2891.594408 2941.352229 2924.165053 2997.881411 3024.234204    10
##    flick(alpha)    8.060392    9.355323   13.646002   10.055176   10.841843   48.312741    10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the values in alpha blind, you can create a for loop and use logic to run up a counter to if this iteration of alpha equals the last. You will need to set a past alpha to accept the current value and compare the next one against.

Once the two values do not agree the counter number is concatenated to the vector you created outside of the loop and the counter goes back to one.

It is simple enough that you should do this yourself to learn how.

You can read a file into a variable, but not manually type in numbers or ever need to make them visible. IF the data is 'protected' in some way...